# How to use a fetched value in INSTR in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I am trying to create a *view* which combines two tables A and B to fetch data.
The main function of this view is to decode the value which A has in one of its column

```
Name~LastName~DOB~placeofBirth
```

As we can see the string is separated by **~**
The Special character **~** is in the table B but also encoded.

```
&~*+
```

My task is to fetch the second character from Table B and then use this for separating values in A as individual values.
Since we cant declare variables in Views where can i store ~ charecter to compare it to values

Below is sample of what im trying to do which is giving me error

```
SELECT 
  Substr(B.SpecialCharecterss,2,1) Delimiter,  

  SUBSTR(A.CodedString,1, INSTR(A.CodedString, Delimiter, 1, 1) -1) , //Throws error here 

 // Similarly other fields
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(coded_string,
                     replace('[^X]+', 'X', substr(chars, 2, 1)),
                     1, 2)
from (select 'Name~LastName~DOB~placeofBirth' as coded_string, '&~*+' as chars from dual) b
```

The last argument is which of the fields you want in `coded_string`.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a common table expression:

```
WITH cteDelimiter AS (SELECT  Substr(B.SpecialCharecterss,2,1) AS Delimiter 
                        FROM B)
SELECT SUBSTR(A.CodedString, 1, INSTR(A.CodedString, d.Delimiter, 1, 1) - 1)
  FROM A
  CROSS JOIN cteDelimiter d
```

Comment: I tried this and getting this Error ORA-32035: unreferenced query name defined in WITH clause

Comment: I don't know your actual table names - are they really `A` and `B` as shown in the question or should `A` and `B` be changed to something else? Also, in your question you reference a column named `SpecialCharecterss` - should this perhaps be `SpecialCharacters`?

Comment: In actual code table and column names are different, I made the changes accordingly in original code , still I'm getting that ORA-32035 error